# Trying to verify if an AD Group is in a specific OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory, contains

I am pulling an event log on a DC every time a user is added to a group. I want to send out an email if a user is added to a group inside a specific OU. I am able to successfully list the name of the group that the user was added to as well as get the list of the group names inside the specific OU but when I try to check to see if the group name from the event is in the list it always comes back as false.

I have tried formatting the **Get-ADGroup** section as a table and list as well as out-string with no luck.
I have also tried using the -in -like and -contains comparison operators. with no luck..

```
$GroupAddEvent = Get-EventLog -ComputerName *DCNAME* -LogName "Security" -InstanceID 4756 -Newest 1
$EventGroup = $($GroupAdditionEvent.ReplacementStrings[2])
$UserResponsible = $($GroupAdditionEvent.ReplacementStrings[6])
$UserAdded = $($GroupAdditionEvent.ReplacementStrings[0])
$GroupEventMessage = $GroupAdditiondEvent.Message
$ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "*OUPATH*" | select name | fl
if($ADGroups.Contains($EventGroup)) {"True"}
else {"False"}
```

The variable `$ADGroups` should come back with all the groups in a specific OU and the variable `$EventGroup` should be the group that I'm looking for in the list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace this line:

```
$ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "*OUPATH*" | select name | fl
```

with:

```
$ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "*OUPATH*" | select -expand name
```

Comment: That looks like it worked! Can you explain to me what I was doing wrong/what the addition of the "-expand" does?

Comment: You formatted the output as a list (fl is an alias for Format-List). This made your $ADGroups variable contain something like:
Name: Group1
Name: Group2
Furthermore your variable will contain several different object types. In short: NEVERR use fl in scripts :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the below:

```
$EventGroup = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "*OUPATH*" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
if($ADGroups -Contains $EventGroup)
```